# VBA - Retrieving Data from Closed Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA script that will gather data from four different Workbooks.  For now, I am just testing the code with one Workbook, but I am receiving an error when I try to acquire the data.  While I would like to retrieve the data from the four Workbooks without opening them, I will need to open them in order to find the last row of data.  Here is my current code:

```
Public Sub GetData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim xlsPath As String
Dim xlsFilename As String
Dim SheetName As String

xlsPath = "C:\Users\a27qewt\My Documents\Document Retention\FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm"

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(xlsPath)

'Workbooks("FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm").Sheets("S&S Document Locations").Unprotect

LastRow = Workbooks("FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm").Sheets("S&S Document Locations").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("SS_Index.xlsm").Sheets("Document Index").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5)).Value = _
Workbooks("FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm").Sheets("S&S Document Locations").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5)).Value

WB.Close False

End Sub
```

I am receiving a 1004 application/object defined error in the `Workbooks("FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm").Sheets("S&S Document Locations").Range`... line.  Any suggestions why?

Comment: When using `Range(Cells(), Cells())` both Range() and Cells() - if not qualified with a worksheet - will refer to the activesheet. You need to specify a worksheet for all parts of that expression.  Your code will be easier to manage if you declare a variable for each sheet and use those references when working with ranges, instead of always using `Workbooks(...).Sheets(...)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for the suggestion.  I was able to successfully use `Range("A2:E" & LastRow)`.  Is there a more efficient  or cleaner method of doing this?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Is it possible to set (define) a workbook without opening it?

Comment: @MrZH6 You can't assign a variable to a workbook which isn't open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved your problem, but here's how I'd approach it

```
Public Sub GetData()

    Dim LastRow As Long '<< not Integer
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim xlsPath As String
    Dim xlsFilename As String
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet, rngSrc As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    xlsPath = "C:\Users\a27qewt\My Documents\Document Retention\FI_DocumentRetention.xlsm"

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(xlsPath)

    Set shtSrc = WB.Sheets("S&S Document Locations")
    Set shtDest = Workbooks("SS_Index.xlsm").Sheets("Document Index")

    LastRow = shtSrc.Cells(shtSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngSrc = shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Range("A2"), _
                              shtSrc.Cells(LastRow, 5))

    shtDest.Range("A2").Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count, _
                               rngSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rngSrc.Value

    WB.Close False

End Sub
```